# What is the better way to create React components when there's a View and Edit functionalities?

Tags: reactjs

I have a use case where I need Edit and View functionality of a Content. Let's take user and admin where user can just view the information and admin can edit the fields (mostly dropdown and text) to show to the user. I have a MainComponent which calls either Edit or View based on the person logging in. View and Edit have separate APIs for my purpose. View just fetches the selected information whereas Edit fetches both the selected and the options available. For example, let's take Difficulty Level: It can be Easy, Medium or Hard. View fetches only value which was selected by Admin whereas Admin fetches all the available options for him(Easy, Medium and Hard) and his previously selected value.

The real situation I have is much more complex with 5-10 API calls (with 10 Dropdowns) in Edit Page whereas View has only 10 Dropdowns and a single API call and its selected values by admin.

I want to know whether my way of splitting component is correct.

Another approach I had in my mind is not to have 2 separate components for View and Edit respectively and have a common Component and use if else case to show either view or edit fields and do API calls based on selection(Edit or View). But I don't have a clear idea on this type of implementation.

The downside of my approach is, if I want to add a new field, I need to do it in 2 places, both Edit and View but good thing here is, Edit looks cleaner and my concern is Edit itself is bulky now and having a common one will make it even more bulkier and unwanted things might load for View(I think).

The downside of my another approach is if in future I want a field, I have to add it both in View and Edit Components.

I am new to react and I want to know which way is better or is there an even better approach. Any suggestion on this would be helpful.

PS: Due to confidentiality reasons, I cannot post the code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, your two components are too different to be the same with some if cases to tweak it around depending if it is a user or an admin connected.

What I would recommend is to have a single higher order component rendering two different dummy component for each type of viewer.

That way, if there are some logic or data that are specific to a single entity, you can just pass it to single dummy component or both if it's generic data.

Your dummy components can also inherit from another components such as you can have: `HOComp => GenericDummyComp => SpecificComp`

Like that if you want to add a new field, you just have to add it in the Generic component and it will be rendered in both generic and specific components.